# Why no "Add a new RSS feed" option in my Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, rss

When I right-click on RSS feeds in one of my accounts, I see this, which is expected:

[image]

In my other account, the **Add a New RSS Feed...** and the **Import an OPMI File...** options are missing:

[image]

Both are Exchange accounts, administered by different companies. In the one with the missing options, I do have RSS feeds that I've added in the past. Any ideas as to why the option isn't there now?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, the Add a New RSS Feed... and the Import an OPMI File... options are only available to the primary account in Outlook. You may create a new Outlook profile and add the second account mentioned in your thread to check the result.

Comment: The one I'm having trouble with is the one marked as the Default account and is listed first in Account Settings. The other account is the one that has the proper menu options. Is "Primary" a different concept than "Default"? If so, how can I change the Primary account? I don't see such an option.

Comment: Is the "default account" the first account you configured in this Outlook profile?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but probably not.